# How to add data in vector to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, svm

I want to use cv::Mat to train Data to SVM but when I use hog.compute, the output is a Vector so I must add it to Mat first.

E.g., if I have

```
vector  test ;
test.push_back(5);
test.push_back(47);

vector test2;
test.push_back(5098);
test.push_back(50);

Mat m[2][2];
```

So how do I add test and test2 Data to m?  I would like a result that looks like {{5,47},{5098,50}}

I tried to use  m[1][1].push_back(test);  but it not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
vector<float> test;
vector<float> test2;
```

You want something like

```
Mat m1(test);
m1.push_back(Mat(test2));
```

Comment: If I don't define matrix size like Mat m1; and I use m1.push_back(Mat(test)); m1.push_back(Mat(test2)); .Is matrix size become m[2][2] and have a result like I want?